# Is it possible that a considerably thicker portion of slab would decrease the moment capacity of a raft slab

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis

If I Design this slab as a flat 1500mm thick slab throughout ignoring the step will the design be conservative. I'm worried the extra stiffness created by the step, will attract the moment into the step as it is acting like a beam and therefore my model may not be conservative and there could be possible failure.

[image: Slab Section]

Comment: You need to add  a LOT more detail here, as well as rewording your entire question as it doesn't make sense as written.  Is the 1500 mm proposed thickness correct, as that's quite a raft?  Is this a professional design by an engineering consultancy or DIY?  Which model is which and which one are you worried about?